# Triple nested while loop - Big Oh Notation - Count of Primitive Operations

Tags: python, algorithm, time, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having some trouble figuring out the primitive count of operations for the following lines of code

```
def question1(n):
    n = n           # 1 ops
    i = 0           # 1 ops
    a = 0           # 1 ops
    while i < n:            # n ops
        j = 0               # n ops
        while j < n:        # n * n ops
            k = 0           # n * n ops
            while k < 60:                   # n * n * 60 ops
                a = i * j - i * 2 + k       # n * n * 60 * 5 ops
                k += 1                      # n * n * 60 * 2 ops
            j += 1          # n * n ops
        i += 1              # n ops

# total sum of prim operations = (n * n * 483) + (3 * n) + 3
```

I'm not sure if

```
            while k < 60:                   # n * n * 60 ops
                a = i * j - i * 2 + k       # n * n * 60 * 5 ops
                k += 1                      # n * n * 60 * 2 ops
```

Is it really

```
n * n * 60?
```

or should it be

```
 n * n * n * 60
```

Comment: The innermost loop should be treated as an `O(1)` operation (if all binary operations are treated as `O(1)` operations).

Comment: The whole point of big O is to overlook multiplicative constants (as well as non dominant terms) so O(60*n^k) is the same as O(n^k).

Comment: If we ignore the constants, should this be O(n^3) or O(n^2) ? I'm hearing different answers and I'm very confused

Comment: There is no n^3 in your expression, so why should it be n^3?

Comment: I thought the Big Oh notation would be O(n^3) since there are triple while loops, but people are saying the most inner loop doesnt count since it's constant, so the Big Oh is O(n^2)

Comment: a while loop (or anything for that matter) that doesn't depend on `n` is constant.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I was treating it as if it depended on '''n'''

Comment: *"primitive operations"* is an ambiguous concept. For instance, a `while` statement will at some point evaluate the condition as false and then make execution jump to the statement *after* the loop. One could say those are 2 operations (evaluation + jump). Someone could say that `k += 1` is 3 operations: load `k` in register, add one to it, store register to `k`. But if Python were compiled into machine language that has `INC` (like NASM), it is only one operation. So all this is fuzzy, and honestly quite useless. You should not identify "primitive operations", but logic that is O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"primitive operations"* is an ambiguous concept. For instance, a `while` statement will at some point evaluate the condition as false (which you didn't count) and then make the execution jump to the statement *after* the loop. One could say those are two operations (evaluation + jump).

Someone could say that `k += 1` should count as 3 operations:

- load the value of `k` into a CPU register,
- add one to it
- store that register's value back in `k`.

But if Python were compiled into a machine language that has the `INC` instruction (like NASM), and we deal with fixed-size integers (like 32 bit), it is only one operation.

So this concept is fuzzy, and it is quite useless to sum them up. You should not identify "primitive operations", but identify chunks of code that have a constant time complexity.

### Analysis in terms of constant time complexity

First we need to decide whether to think of integer arithmetic operations to be [constant in time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), or whether we should take into consideration that integers (certainly in Python) can have arbitrary size, and therefore these operations do [*not* have a constant time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations). See also ["bit complexity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity#Resources). I will assume here that you want to regard arithmetic operations as having a constant time complexity.

Then we can identify this chunk of code has having a constant time complexity:

```
            k = 0
            while k < 60:
                a = i * j - i * 2 + k
                k += 1
            j += 1
```

Note here that executing the inner block (that has a constant complexity) 60 times, still means the total has a constant time complexity, since 60 is a constant (independent from the input).

Also the initialisation of integer variables or their incrementing all represent constant time complexity.

There are two nested loops that each iterate  times when they get executed. So that means the (above) inner part gets executed ² times.

Hence, the overal time complexity is O(²)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is definitely not n * n * n * 60. You might be confused about asymptotic notation, which may be influencing this question in the first place. The third while loop is executed 60 times, meaning that each operation within it is executed 60 times. This while loop runs 60 times for each of the n iterations of the second while loop, which runs n times for each of the n iterations of the first while loop, yielding n * n * 60.

Although the 60 is involved here, it is still a constant and is therefore of little significance for large values of n. The use of a triple nested loop is more of a trick question in this case, designed to show an example of why the polynomial properties of the algorithm are more important than any constants, just because as n gets large, n * n becomes much larger than 60 does.

Your calculation looks correct, though. The only thing missed is that the following blocks are actually 2 operations each :

```
j += 1          # n * n * 2 ops, equal to j = j + 1, an assignment AND addition
i += 1          # n * 2 ops ( i = i + 1 )
```

Comment: You are totally right, I overlooked those operations at the end.

Comment: So would you say the Big O notation of this algorithm is O(n^2)?